# Why drop table failed in impala-shell but works in Hue/Impala?

Tags: cloudera, impala, hue

This is very odd to me, I have a small Cloudera cluster that is NOT kerberorised. I am able to run drop table query in Hue/Impala but not able to do it in impala-shell.

Below code is from impala-shell:

```
[hadoop01:21000] > use client1;
Query: use client1
[hadoop01:21000] > show tables;
Query: show tables
+--------------------------------------+
| name                                 |
+--------------------------------------+
| loadstats_201812_q2_grouped_by_month |
| loanstats_201812_q2_staged           |
+--------------------------------------+
Fetched 2 row(s) in 0.01s
```

Note below I am to drop the first table:

```
[hadoop01:21000] > DROP TABLE IF EXISTS client1.loanStats_201812_q2_grouped_by_month purge;
Query: drop TABLE IF EXISTS client1.loanStats_201812_q2_grouped_by_month purge
```

There is no error reported, I thought it is dropped, but it is NOT

```
[hadoop01:21000] > show tables;
Query: show tables
+--------------------------------------+
| name                                 |
+--------------------------------------+
| loadstats_201812_q2_grouped_by_month |
| loanstats_201812_q2_staged           |
+--------------------------------------+
Fetched 2 row(s) in 0.01s
```

Role/Group check:

In Hue, I belong to "default" group that has the following permissions:

[image]

In the host I ran impala-shell, I am in wheel/sudo group.

On hdfs, I am in wheel.

What else can I check? Any clue is appreciated, thank you very much in advance.

Comment: What is your CDH version?

Comment: CDH 5.12, thank you.

Comment: Maybe there is a snycronization problem between impala and metastore. After running "invalidate metadata" on that db, did you see the same result?

Comment: No, invalidate doesn't bring magic

Comment: Is there results when you select the dropped the table?

Comment: Have a look in Cloudera Manager and check the clusters/impala/queries to see what was logged for the drop